# fatal error when compile linux kernel 5.0 on board exynos4412

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm

hope  i could explain the question

i have a board- exynos4412, i try to run linux kernel 5.0 on my board.

when i compiled the kernel, a error i can't understand occured.

`arch/arm/boot/dts/exynos4.dtsi:19:10: fatal error: dt-bindings/clock/exynos4.h: No such file or directory`

but i checked the folder，`linux-5.0/include/dt-bindings/exynos4.h` is there..... could anyone help me.....

my process:

1. `cp arch/arm/configs/exynos_defconfig .`
2. `make ARCH=arm menuconfig`
3. `config something`
4. `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbors.jpg)

Comment: `dt-bindings/clock/exynos4.h` is not the same as `linux-5.0/include/dt-bindings/exynos4.h`. Can't say more because you've not included any more relevant info.

Comment: Its working on my side. Can you try this and show us the output. "make ARCH=arm  exynos4210-origen.dtb" and have you modified the dts? and anything related to it in config file

Comment: thanks to all，i have figure it out。The reason is that i unziped the source code to the shared folder between my computer and the virtual machine.  In the path - linux-5.0/arch/arm/boot/dts/, a folder named include dispear,in the include folder there should be a symbolink to linux-5.0/include/dtbindings/. so compile failed...i unziped the source code in my virtual machine directly,and compile succeed...  thank you Lalimba,and R.K.Lohana